# Android Button being too resource-intensive

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, android-button

I have a simple app with several buttons, sometimes the user needs to press a combination of buttons to send the correct query.  However, upon testing, I found the buttons are not very resoponsive when pressed a little quickly.  I think this has to do with the Android buttons being relatively more resource intensive.  I was wondering if there is any way to make the button more responsive (perhaps through a lighter View?)  Or if I can put a straight HTML page with HTML buttons in a WebView?  Would that be more responsive?

Comment: What exactly are you doing in the click handlers for those `Buttons`?

Comment: Typical handler would be simply appending String for query.         leftButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
         public void onClick(View btn){
            addendum="%E5%B7%A6"; 
         }
        });

Comment: Could it be that I am using an extra selector xml for a different button image for the button pressed state?  And would the responsiveness be improved if I use an ImageButton instead of a Button with background set to a selector xml file?

Comment: If you only set a string in the `onClick` handlers that should be pretty fast(also I don't know what you understand by *not very responsive*). Is that image for the pressed state big?

Comment: I deleted all background image for my buttons, and now they are more responsive.  I think if you are trying to create an app that users tend to use when they are impatient, it's best avoiding the state selector to avoid getting on their nerves.

Comment: Considering that a `Button` uses a `StateListDrawable` by default, your claim seems overly broad. There might be something peculiar with your `StateListDrawable` that was causing problems.